# How to show SPECIFIC hidden files on mac?

Tags: macos, file, hidden

Such as by file extension?

For instance, I don't want to see .DS_STORE files, but I want to see all .htaccess files.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type

```
 ls -a | grep -G .YOUR_EXTENSION$
```

See http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html for more information of regex
Also `man grep` and `man ls` will be of use

Comment: I tried typing this in Terminal, but it doesn't make the files show. Is there another step perhaps at the beginning or and the end of this line?  I tried typing: ls -a | grep -G .htaccess$